# "All plugins are updated" but they aren't

Tags: plugins, updates

i'm using Wordpress since like....2013 or before, can't really remember.

So, basically, my problem is that there is NO WAY (a part uploading those manually via FTP or via "Upload a new plugin") to let Wordpress Check if my plugins are updated or not.

In my experience, it's a **pretty common problem across the wordpress community**. Soon or later, Wordpress **totally stops to notify you about plugin available updates**, until i ran into infinite random problem that i later notice it's caused by a non-updated plugin.

There is a way to know **why this happens and how solve it?** (how does wordpress check for available plugin updates?)
I tried **disabling pretty much all plugins** and **nothing changed.**

Comment: I haven’t heard of this being a common problem. Which plugins are you not being notified about? Are you sure they aren’t just ‘premium’ plugins whose licenses have expired? Keep in mind that unless a plugin was downloaded from Wordpress.org, then any update notifications are up to the plugin to implement, and if they stop working then it’s the plugin’s fault and you’ll need to speak to its author.

Comment: I had this problem many times in many years with different hostings/wordpress installations/plugins so i guess its a common problem (or i'm just super unlucky). No, no premium plugin. ALL plugins are not being notified, every single one. No licenses. Every single plugin was downloaded from the official wordpress store or how its called. Nothing out of the repos.